# help about Spring controller mapping problems

Tags: spring-mvc

i've got probles while some spring sample project.

My intension is that click the link In index.jsp, go to login page.
like this `<a href="/login.html">log in</a>`
Login Controller cover with login process and redirect to login form from index.

And html is mapping in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

if i click the link, get "HTTP Status 404 - /login.html"
help me plz!

peice of codes like this.

LoginController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
@SessionAttributes("login")
public class LoginController {
    private LoginValidator loginValidator;
    private MemberService memberService;
    private Provider<LoginInfo> loginInfoProvider;

    @Inject     
    public void setLoginInfoProvider(Provider<LoginInfo> loginInfoProvider) {
        this.loginInfoProvider = loginInfoProvider;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void init(LoginValidator loginValidator, MemberService memberService) {
        this.loginValidator = loginValidator;
        this.memberService = memberService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showform(){
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/login.html");
}

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@ModelAttribute @Valid Login login, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) return "login";

        this.loginValidator.validate(login, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "login";
        }
        else {
            memberService.login(loginInfoProvider.get().currentMember());
            status.setComplete();
            return "redirect:/members.html"; // don't mind this... modifing.....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at your server's logfiles, the answer is in there.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you loaded the Spring Dispatcher servlet before mapping them inside your web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Based on your code, I am assuming you are using a view resolver so double check you have this in place as well

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Check your server error log and console. Most of the time, it will give you great information for debug especially 404 error page. Also I am a bit confused at your code. For your global REQUESTMAPPING, you have the value set to "login" but for your REQUESTMETHOD.GET you have a redirection to "login" again. I am surprised that you dont have infinite loop redirection.

Answer (score 0):

thank for your answer but i already use codes.

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're defining the mapping incorrectly.  Your LoginController responds to requests for "/login"; however, requests for "/login.html" most likely get mapped to a different controller and method defined elsewhere.  That is to say, "/login" != "/login.html".

If I were you, I would use a more RESTful style of URL mapping by linking it this way: `<a href="/login/">log in</a>`.  Then your LoginController would map cleanly.  When linking to pages from your HTML, try not to use extensions (.html, .jsp, .whatever).  Instead, just link to raw paths ending in the "/" suffix.

Complete example:

HTML:
`<a href="/login/">Login</a>`

Java:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login/")
...
```

P.S.: I would even get rid of the form processing code altogether and use Spring Security instead to handle the authentication.